# Custom Button - Doesn't ask for Record Type

Tags: urlhacking

I have the following button code:

```
/a0M/e?CF00N80000003Z5Zc={!Employees__c.Name}
&CF00N80000003Z5Zc_lkid={!Employees__c.Id} 
&00N80000003Z93X={!YEAR( TODAY() )}
&Name={!Employees__c.Name} {!TODAY()}
&00N80000003iwMY={!TODAY()}
&CF00N80000003Z5Yo={!Employees__c.Account__c}
&retURL=%2F{!Employees__c.Id}
&ent=01I80000000OULj
&RecordType=01280000000Bqev
```

If I take out &RecordType=01280000000Bqev the system uses the default record type instead of asking me to choose from the list of 5 or so I have. The standard New button shows me all the record types so it is not something related to access.

How do you get a URL hack to ask for record type?

**Fix using answer as a guide**

Here is my final button code.

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I80000000OULj&save_new_‌​
url=%2Fa0M%2Fe%3FCF0‌​0N80000003Z5Zc={!Emp‌​loyees__c.Name} 
&CF00N80000003Z5Zc_lkid={!Employees__c.Id} &00N80000003Z93X={!YEAR( TODAY() )} 
&Name={!Employees__c.Name} {!TODAY()} &00N80000003iwMY={!TODAY()} 
&CF00N80000003Z5Yo={!Employees__c.Account__c} &retURL=%2F{!Employees__c.Id} 
&ent=01I80000000OULj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity&save_new_url=%2Fa0M%2Fe%3FCF00N80000003Z5Zc={!Employees__c.Name}
&CF00N80000003Z5Zc_lkid={!Employees__c.Id} 
&00N80000003Z93X={!YEAR( TODAY() )}
&Name={!Employees__c.Name} {!TODAY()}
&00N80000003iwMY={!TODAY()}
&CF00N80000003Z5Yo={!Employees__c.Account__c}
&retURL=%2F{!Employees__c.Id}
&ent=01I80000000OULj
```

I have not tested so you may need to tweak but you essentially need to pass through the parameters to the `recordtypeselect.jsp` page.

You may also be able to use your original URL and remove any personal settings you have for default recordtypes. This should force the recordtype selection. Again, not tested and not ideal either as you each individual user would have to do this.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that is what I was missing. Here is my final button code.
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I80000000OULj&save_new_url=%2Fa0M%2Fe%3FCF00N80000003Z5Zc={!Employees__c.Name}
&CF00N80000003Z5Zc_lkid={!Employees__c.Id} 
&00N80000003Z93X={!YEAR( TODAY() )}
&Name={!Employees__c.Name} {!TODAY()}
&00N80000003iwMY={!TODAY()}
&CF00N80000003Z5Yo={!Employees__c.Account__c}
&retURL=%2F{!Employees__c.Id}
&ent=01I80000000OULj